# Thread.currentThread().interrupt() vs. this.interrupt() from within Runnable#run()

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to figure out why every example on the Internet I found on how to catch `interrupt()` from within the `Runnable#run()` method, they all look like this:

```
while (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    //foo();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptingException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    //foo();
}
```

I understand threads enough now (I think so) and I can't understand why if we're inside the `run` method doesn't it mean that we could replace `Thread.currentThread()` by `this`?

Comment: No but thanks for answer

Comment: @Amin, of course, that's not duplicate of the one you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for mention. I think they are same.

Comment: It's worth noting that the general contract of the "interrupted" state of a thread is that any method that waits for a long time should notice if the thread was interrupted. If the interruption prevents the method from doing what it would normally do, it should throw an `InterruptedException` to its caller; if it completes normally it should re-interrupt the thread so the interruption signal isn't lost. In a thread you create, you can choose to ignore interruption signals, but in a `Runnable` which may run on a different thread, you should usually not ignore an interruption if it occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*if we're inside the run method doesn't it mean that Thread.currentThread() == this?*

No. In the `run` method of a `Runnable`, `this` does not equals `current thread`, it represents current `Runnable` instance.

`Runnable` is just a normal object which can be used to construct a new thread. When you use a `Runnable` to construct `Thread` :

```
Runnable runnable = ...
Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
```

the thread and the runnable are still different objects.

---

This exmaple shows that they are different things:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("inner runnable: " + this);   // inner runnable: com.Test$1@34ce8af7
        }
    };


    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);

    System.out.println("thread:  " + thread); // thread:  Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
    System.out.println("runnable:  " + runnable); // runnable:  com.Test$1@34ce8af7

    thread.start();
    thread.join();
}
```

---

Another thing worth noting is that `java.lang.Thread` also implements `Runnable` interface, so if you create a `Thread` directly and override the `run` method, `this` keyword and `Thread.currentThread` will both refers current thread instance.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // this == Thread.currentThread()
    }
};
```

---

Also you can refer current thread in any method, whether you can in the `run` method or not, for example, in `main` method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` inside `Runnable#run()` refers to `Runnable` object, not to the enclosing `Thread` object. In this case `Thread.currentThread() != this`.

However if create the thread object like below, which is discouraged:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() == this);
  }
};
```

then `Thread.currentThread() == this`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only replace `this` with `Thread.currentThread()` if `this` is the thread.  This would require extending the `Thread` which is very rarely a good idea.

Never the less you don't need to use `Thread.currentThread()` like this as an exception can break a loop anyway.

```
try {
    while (true){
        try {
            //foo();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } finally {
            //foo();
        }
    }
} catch (InterruptingException e){
     // if the thread needs to continue after an interrupt.
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

I would tend to assume an interrupted thread should stop ASAP, in which case shouldn't have any work after being interrupted ideally.